# RESTful API with either Tomcat or Node.js?

Tags: java, node.js, rest, tomcat, typescript

I am at a decision fork where i have to pick whether to use Tomcat or Node.js in my project and need advice from experts on this.

Some questions that i have here are:

1. Is Tomcat (Java) or Node.js with Typescript better suited to write a RESTful API which gets values form a Database and has to interact with a another java component?
2. Does Node.js have unit-testing support?
3. Is it possible to use websockets with Tomcat for another component of the API which pushes Data to the client?
4. Is the type system of Java better than the system of Typescript (not all dependencies are available in Typescript (or?) and therefore don’t have types?)?

Comment: Tomcat shouldn't be your first pick when it comes to a java based backend. There are other alternatives such as the [play framework](https://www.playframework.com), [Akka http](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/http/), [Spark](http://sparkjava.com) or you can even create something REALLY fast using just [Netty](http://netty.io).

Comment: I picked Tomcat because it has a lot of documentation and you find easily help because a lot of  developers already know tomcat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat and Node.js are really totally different from each other, so there is no one to one comparison.

While [Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) is a *web server*, [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) is a server side *runtime* *environment* - and therein lies all the difference. Java - and consequently the web and application servers supporting it - give an architectural foundation to your application which arguably no other technology can offer. On the other hand, the speed, flexibility and simplicity of JavaScript (and therefore Node.js) is a winner.

So the real question you should be asking is - do you want a robust application with solid foundation or a speedy, flexible solution?

There are also a slew of other factors to consider such as memory, performance, maintainability, and the likes.

Here are some links that might help:
[Performance comparison](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-comparison-between)

[Java vs. Node.js:](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2883328/java/java-vs-nodejs-an-epic-battle-for-developer-mindshare.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes Tomcat Support [websocket in tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html). If you have already some written  component in java you should use java.

You can use jersey , spring boot to implement your rest webservices.

If you are working with nosql kind of databases then nodejs could be better bet